# Wildfly server configuration in eclipse(STS) for hot deployment

Tags: eclipse, configuration, wildfly, hotdeploy

I am configuring Wildfly server in eclipse(STS). While configuring, I noticed the following option:

> Server is externally managed. Assume server is started.

What does this option do ?
Does it impact capability of hot deployment of jsps etc.
Can someone also point to a location where all these options are described in detail for Wildfly server configuration in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

> "The Server is externally managed. Assume server is started" field is used when the user wants to deploy the server but does not want the IDE to stop or start the server for them. Depending on the requirements, select this check box or leave it unchecked, as is default.

http://tools.jboss.org/documentation/howto/configure_remote_server.html